# NGINX and BOOST for Drupal 7 locking certain pages?

Tags: boost, nginx, drupal-7, php

I have a Drupal 7 site with NGINX & Boost. Almost everything is working perfect and cached pages are served very very fast.

The problem is that some pages, randomly, won't load. Once a page gets "locked" it simply won't load until PHP-FPM is restarted. After I restart PHP-FPM a different page(s) wont load, and also this page(s) will work only after PHP-FPM is restarted again... and so on.

I think it's not an error with Drupal or NGINX because locked pages load correctly after restarting PHP-FPM. I guess it's a random thing causing PHP-FPM to "lock" certain processes  (sorry if it doens't make sense).

Thanks for your help!

PD: I have perusio's config for Drupal 7 with Nginx using drupal_boost.conf

Comment: you defined `locked` as `won't load`, but you should probably elaborate on what `won't load` means exactly.

Comment: You are right @Coder1, thanks for your point of view.